# Is it possible to put a graphicImage inside f:selectItem itemLabel?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, selectonemenu

I want to put an image using `p:graphicImage` inside an itemLabel of an `f:selectItem` so that the image becomes the label of the item, is it possible to do that, if yes, what is the syntax of doing that? for example:

```
<f:selectItem itemLabel="put graphicImage Here" itemValue="Pale white" />
```

Note: what i mean is that i want to hard code the `p:graphicImage` element directly inside the `itemLabel`

Comment: Yes it is possible. Check the example [about `<p:selectOneMenu>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectOneMenu.jsf) in PrimeFaces showcase.

Comment: i don't want to read from an ArrayList i want to hardCode the p:graphicImage directly inside the itemLabel

Comment: Have you at least tried it?

Comment: @JavaPlayer hardcode it on the managed bean and retrieve it on itemLabel.

Comment: yes i tried it but i doesn't work, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16792660/primefaces-selectonemenu-not-rendering-images-and-strings

Comment: @Diogo ok, again how to put the p:graphicImage inside the itemLabel ??

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. Use [HTML Escape Characters](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php) to build your `<img /> Tag`

Yours will probably looks like this:

`<f:selectItem itemEscaped="false" itemLabel="&lt;img src=&quot;/icons/your-icon.svg&quot; /&gt;" itemValue="true" />`

Obs.: Dont forget to use a converter.

> Take a look at [How to escape f:selectItem itemLabel attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238646/how-to-escape-fselectitem-itemlabel-attribute)